# custom dialogbox with custom listview get items

Tags: android

I have a custom dialog box, that contains a listview with custom items in it. It has 2 textviews and a checkbox, when the user clicks on ok, how can i send the items that are checked to the activity that opened the custom dialog box? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback interfaces. Define an interface and implement it in your dialog box. Also in your activity use your interface as a variable and send it to your dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

please see follwing code

```
       AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                DialogActivity.this);
        builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builderSingle.setTitle("Select One Name:-");
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                DialogActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
        arrayAdapter.add("Hardik");
        arrayAdapter.add("Archit");
        arrayAdapter.add("Jignesh");
        arrayAdapter.add("Umang");
        arrayAdapter.add("Gatti");
        builderSingle.setNegativeButton("cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String strName = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);
                        AlertDialog.Builder builderInner = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                DialogActivity.this);
                        builderInner.setMessage(strName);
                        builderInner.setTitle("Your Selected Item is");
                        builderInner.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                        builderInner.show();
                    }
                });
        builderSingle.show();
```